# Помощь в строках и регулярных выражениях

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Народ помогите пожалуйста. Смотрите, у меня есть предложение "мама мыла раму. Папа большой молодец". А результат должен получится "раму мыла мама. Молодец большой папа".  Но по коду у меня меняются первое слово  предложение и последнее слово последнего предложения.

```
public static void changing_place(String s) {
    String[] words = s.split(" ");//Разбиение строки на слова
    String temp = words[0];//записуем первое слово
    words[0] = words[words.length - 1];//находим послднее слово
    words[words.length - 1] = temp;// говорим что бып послденее записалось в первое
    for (String word : words) {//перебираем и записуем в новую строку
        System.out.print(word + " ");//выводим
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: По какому коду?

Comment: Просто с мобильного не очень удобно . Буду дома кину код

Comment: Ну смотрите, судя по вашему коду, Вам нужно изменить 3 и 4 строки а 5 и 8 ую поменять местами. По идее должно выводить парвильно

Comment: То есть я меняю услови и немного переставляю порядок выполнения кода

Answer (score 5):

```
// важно, что в конце точка, а за ней пробел
String source = "мама мыла раму. Папа большой молодец. ";
String result = source.replaceAll("([^. ]+) ([^.]+) ([^. ]+)\\. ", "$3 $2 $1. ");
// result == "раму мыла мама. молодец большой Папа. "
```

Рассмотрим регулярное выражении подробнее:

> `([^. ]+) ([^.]+) ([^. ]+)\\.`

Каждый такой блок будет отвечать за одно предложение. 
Регулярное выражение состоит из трёх частей:

> `([^. ]+)`, `([^.]+)` и `([^. ]+)\\.`

Первая часть *`([^. ]+)`* отвечает за первое слово в предложении. Запись `[^. ]` означает **"любой символ кроме точки и пробела"**. 
Плюсик повторяет предыдущий символ положительное число раз, поэтому запись *`[^. ]+`* означает **"любой символ кроме точки и пробела, повторённый положительное число раз"**, то есть как раз первое слово предложения. Мы берём *`[^. ]+`* в скобки, чтобы можно было в замещающей строке (второй аргумент функции *String.replaceAll()*) обращаться к первому слову предложения как `$1`

Comment: Очень понятно и докладно . Спасибо большое

Comment: Дмитрий ещё один вопрос [^. ]-эта конструкция отвечает за превое слово и обращаемся мы к нему$1 к последнему слову мы обращаемся $3. А $2 мы обращаемся к слову которое посередине правильно ?

Comment: Не совсем, $2 это все слова которые между первым и последним. Если в предложении всего три слова, то $2 действительно отвечает за среднее слово, но когда в предложении больше трёх слов, то и $2 состоит нескольких слов.

Comment: Дмитрий я понял. А если домустим предложение из 5 слов. И мне нужно поменять  5 слово на 3. То я добавляю [^. ]+ и  $4.

Comment: Да, нужно будет добавить две штуки [^. ]+ (чтобы в начале регулярки три раза стояло [^. ]+) и замещающей строкой взять "$1 $2 $5 $4 $3"

Comment: Спасибо вчера уже сам поковырял ) может есть какой нибудь сайт который поможет лучше разобраться в регулярных выпадениях

Comment: Google предлагает [quizful](http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-RegExp), мне при написании ответа очень помогла [эта](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) ссылка